# Is using web requests more efficient than socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a Node.js project in which the front end needs to request some data from the back end. Since it only has to do so once per session, I was thinking of using web requests instead of socket.io because I don't need a continuous connection between the front end and the back end all the time.

So my question is: How much, if at all, will the efficiency of my project increase if I use web requests instead of socket.io?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're making a one-time request from client to server, there is no reason to use a continuous socket.io connection or to create a socket.io connection, use it for one message and then disconnect it.

It will certainly be simpler to just use a single http request to get your data.

> How much, if at all, will the efficiency of my project increase?

The main difference would be at high scale your server wouldn't need to handle lots of simultaneous socket.io connections.  At small scale, you probably won't notice much of difference either way.  The main reason for choosing an http request is that it's the simpler and proper architecture for making a single request from client to server.  A socket.io connection has it's uses for different circumstances.